# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try to compile a ionic android application for the first time but cordova fail to compile and i can't find why !

- I've installed openJDK and set $JAVA_HOME in my .bashrc
- I've installed android studio and set $ANDROID_HOME in my .bashrc

but when I `run ionic cordova build android --verbose` or `ionic cordova build android --verbose`, command fail with this errors :

`No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Android Studio project detected
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "MyApp" to /var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (0.0.1): 1
Wrote out Android package name "io.ionic.starter" to /var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/io/ionic/starter/MainActivity.java
Updating icons at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
Updating splash screens at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=/home/agenceho5/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
    at /var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:362:19
    at _fulfilled (/var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/var/ionic/cauterets/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)`

Where is the problem ?
Thank's in advance

EDIT : I've also tryed with openjdk-8 but i've exactly the same error

Comment: this comment seam to resolve this problem : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3115#issuecomment-386625912. After i've a second problem with grabble who's solved by a simple sudo apt install gradle